# Confirming something and at the same time expressing your previous lack of knowledge

Tags: ambiguity, implication

Someone informs me:

> I think it's going to rain.

I check the weather Service and I find the forecast includes rain. I want to share this additional information with the person who informed me. I could say:

> The forecast actually/indeed says it's going to rain.

But I feel *actually* or *indeed* suggests this is obvious to me, the person is therefore providing useless information, and what I'm actually saying is like:

> Oh really? The forecast indeed says it's going to rain.

How can I say it with emphasizing instead the information was useful, it led me to check the forecast, and I'm *now* able to share an additional information that can be useful too? I'd like to keep a short sentence.

Comment: Do you have to say that in one sentence?

Comment: @Cardinal: That would be better in my case.

Comment: How about "your forecast was right, I checked it already"

Comment: @Ahmad: That seems good too. Just I wouldn't add *already*, as this seems to suggest I checked *before* the person talked to me.

Comment: "You are right, the forecast says it's going to rain". It always makes people happy when you say "You are right".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may say:

> Your prediction **turned to be correct**! The weather forecast says it's going to rain.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
 "I just checked, and the forecast agrees with you."
```

Comment: That looks good. You seem to confirm there is no adverb to use in place of *indeed*?

Comment: 'Actually' would be used if you disagreed and were trying to correct him. Indeed is used when agreeing, but using it doesn't have any implication as to why you might agree, just that you do. I suppose you might say "I just checked the forecast, and indeed you were correct."